Dot Product Intuition help
I'm in a quest for understanding the dot product. I thought of the same base case here, but the proof that by rotating both vectors won't change the dot product isn't intuitive, does anyone have any intuitive proof that it won't change, I tried some calculus to get some terms cancel out and end with $cos(\theta)$ again but here is what I came with to prove the inductive step that for any $v$ and $v'$ (v rotated by $d\theta$) won't change anything but it became messy and I couldn't get even further. Any help would be appreciated.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Given two vectors and the right triangle to project one onto the other, notice that rigidly rotating the entire space does not change the length of the projection...

One intutition is that, for vectors based at the origin, the angle between them is determined (via the law of cosines) by the vector lengths and the distance between their tips. But distances don't change under rotations, so the angle can't either. (You could of course argue that this just pushes the problem back to "why is it obvious that rotations preserve distances...")

@EricTowers This doesn't imply that the dot product by this definition $\sum_{i=0}^n u_i \cdot v_i$ is unchanged.

If $e$ is a unit vector then $u.e$ is the projection of $u$ on the direction e This is not affected by rotation. Now rescale $v$ to show that $u.v$ is not affected by rotation.

@Semiclassical This is exactly why I wrote this question: why does it preserve distances? I like how you phrased it.

The question you've asked is unclear. Is your question about the dot product or the rotation? Is there a reason why other answers in the link you posted aren't helpful?

Isn't a linear transformation that preserves the canonical dot product the definition of a rotation on $\mathbb{R}^n$? The other way around you have to define a class of matrices that you call rotations then just show they preserve dot products

Intuitively, when you rotate a vector, you're just moving it in a circle; in 2D, its components are always $r (\cos{\phi},\ \sin{\phi})$ for some fixed $r$ and some varying $\phi$. Consider two 2D vectors $r_u (\cos{\phi_u},\ \sin{\phi_u});\ r_v (\cos{\phi_v},\ \sin{\phi_v})$; do their dot product, use the product-to-sum trigonometric formulas to turn it all to cosines, simplify to get $r_u r_v\cos{(\phi_u - \phi_v)}$. What happens when you add the same $\alpha$ to both angles?

Do not vandalize your own question.

The dot product is intimately connected with Euclidean length.  From the dot product, we can produce lengths, by $||u||^2 = (u,u)$, and furthermore if we know lengths we can determine the dot product via the polarization identity (try proving it yourself!) $$(u,v) = \frac{1}{4}(||u+v||^2 - ||u-v||^2).$$
It's intuitively pretty clear that rotations preserve length (you can't make a stick longer by spinning it around.)  This means that  $||Ru|| = ||u||$, for any rotation $R$. Rotations are also linear.  So if $R$ is your rotation, we have
\begin{align*}
(Ru, Rv) &= \frac{1}{4}(||Ru+Rv||^2 - ||Ru-Rv||^2) \\
&= \frac{1}{4}(||R(u+v)||^2 - ||R(u-v)||^2) \\
&= \frac{1}{4}(||(u+v)||^2 - ||(u-v)||^2) \\
&= (u,v).
\end{align*}.
Even if you don't remember the exact formula for the polarization identity, the point is that you can always recover the dot product if you can measure lengths of things, and so a linear transformation that preserves lengths (an isometry) must preserve the dot product too.
